# Someone can help me find these 3 commands?

Tags: linux

I’m making only one question to avoid spamming. I have 3 situations where I don't know which commands I should use. They are:

1. List all files that have **at least** 3 letters on its name.
2. Count how many files exist with “writing permissions to the owner.”
3. I have a `BD.txt` file with the following content (For example):

> ```
> Mary:Boston:20
> John:New York:18
> Paul:New York:25
> Andrew:New Paris:30
> ```

I have to show how many people live in New York. Generally, I use:

```
cat BD.txt | grep **place_name** | wc -l
```

But this only works if I want to find a single word. If I type “New York,” the command will count all lines that have the name “New,” ignoring the rest (due the space character).

What should I use in these situations?

Comment: I would be happy if my homework was just this. I'm trying to do this for many hours, I just need help with this part.

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions in a single question.  Ask a question, show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Your first, second and third question are all solved with something called Regular Expressions or something called Filename Expansion. _Reply if in need of links to learning material_.

Comment: @dogDLL Please, I would be glad. I'm studing this but I couldn't find enough material to solve this.

Comment: @godDLL I don't think Regex is required at all - indeed basic commands like cut and grep don't even support regex in some versions (maybe I've just become very good at avoiding it though !)

Comment: @Kleber here, go over these, I think it will help you out: 1. [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) 2.[bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) 3.[RegEx](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2012/06/beginners-guide-gnu-grep-basics-regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and help somewhat without doing your homework for you -

Question 1 - Listing files:  The "?" character denotes exactly 1 (not null) wildcard character while the "*" character denotes 0 or more characters.

Question 2 - ls -l will display the permissions for each file at the beginning of a line and the cut command can be used to pick a character or range of characters.   In the case of ls -l, if the third character is "w" it means the owner has write permissions.

Question 3 -  There are a couple of things you are missing - when you are using grep in the way you contemplate you don't use "*" characters - grep is looking for the given substring.   The characters ' and " are used to specify a string of characters - including the space character - as a single parameter.  The '\' character will make whatever character is immediately afterwards be interpreted literally, rather then as something to be expanded by the shell.    (This answer gives at least 3 solutions, btw)